# Jquery pageX and pageY return different coordinates on different devices. How do I normalize this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates

I want to trigger an event using the pageX and pageY coordinates on an image. But since the width and height changes on different devices, so does the values of pageX and pageY. How do i normalize the value across all devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the relative position on the image you are clicking, just convert the position (relative to the top left of the image) to a **percentage** (top left would be 0%, 0% and bottom right would be 100%, 100%) by dividing by the image width / height and use that in your handler.